# About python re raw pattern search

Tags: python, regex

I want to perform re.search using the pattern as a raw string like below.

```
m=re.search(r'pattern',string)
```

But if I have the 'pattern' in variable like `pat='pattern'`. How do I perform raw search?

Comment: Initialize your variable as raw string - `pat = r'pattern'`

Comment: @RohitJain: Answering is better than commenting ;).
@nitins: just a minor point, you can have a better name than `m` :)

Comment: Thanks 0xc0de for that tip about variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare the pattern string as a raw string:

```
regexpattern = r'pattern'
m=re.search(regexpattern,string)
```

Answer (score -3):

you can give the raw input this way. test is the string variable.

```
pat = """pat%s""" % test

pattern = re.compile(pat, re.I | re.M)

match = pattern.search(l)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. Triple quotes != raw string.  Also, why include the string "pat" in the search variable? And why include `re.I` and `re.M`?