# Regex python attaching raw to string variables

Tags: python, regex

Normally you would put an `r` in front of the string to make it raw, but how to do this with a variable (string)?

This is what I tried so far:

```
import re
var = "++"
re.search(r"++", "++")      # also does not work
re.search(var, "++")        # fails
re.search(r(var), "++")     # fails
re.search(r + var, "++")    # fails
re.search("r" + var, "++")  # fails
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18733804/1578604).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible, the string comes from a file and I can't assign because of that?

Comment: Raw strings are just ways to put characters into strings that would otherwise be interpreted as escape sequences. If you're reading from a file, then it doesn't apply - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: ``re.search(r"++", "++")`` does not work for me (python 2.7.5), as expected --- becuase "++" is not a valid regex. ``+`` is a special symbol, and you need to escape it if you want to match it.

Comment: @Bogdan You are correct, this also does not work.

Comment: It is a duplicate, voting to close (though I certainly wasn't able to find it by this title).

Comment: You can try using the [`.encode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) function on the variable.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a valid duplicate either - you kind of want `re.escape()` but only to escape the first `+` :).... So, I'm really not sure, as `++` as a raw string makes no diff. anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `re.escape()` function for this.

```
>>> import re
>>> var = "++"
>>> re.search(re.escape(var), '++')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02B36B80>
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense, as `r` instructs the interpreter on how to interpret a string you put in a source code file. In your example you would have `var = r"++"`, and then you can use `var`. It does not modify string contents, it's just a way of saying what do you want to put in a string. So `var = "\\n"` is equivalent to `var = r"\n"` - `var` variable will contain exactly the same bytes and from then on, you can't change them with any modifiers. These modifiers exist and have any effect only during parsing source code file stage - when the program is running, in the compiled byte code there is no trace of them.